# Подскажите как сортировать массив по одинаковые (value)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*У меня есть такой массив где очередность по id*

```
const menu = [
  { id: 1, cot: 13, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 2, cot: 13, name: 'Aghgrt' },
  { id: 3, cot: 15, name: 'Brt' },
  { id: 4, cot: 13, name: 'dfr' },
  { id: 5, cot: 19, name: 'cft' },
  { id: 6, cot: 19, name: 'Atgh' },
  { id: 7, cot: 15, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 8, cot: 19, name: 'yrt' },
  { id: 9, cot: 13, name: 'Arr' },
  { id: 10, cot: 15, name: 'Yym' },
  { id: 11, cot: 19, name: 'Aryhh' },
  { id: 12, cot: 13, name: 'Arhjthj' },
];
```

*Но мне надо сортировать так чтоб очередь был по cot *

```
const menu2 = [
  { id: 1, cot: 13, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 2, cot: 13, name: 'Aghgrt' },
  { id: 12, cot: 13, name: 'Arhjthj' },
  { id: 9, cot: 13, name: 'Arr' },
  { id: 4, cot: 13, name: 'dfr' },
  { id: 5, cot: 19, name: 'cft' },
  { id: 8, cot: 19, name: 'yrt' },
  { id: 6, cot: 19, name: 'Atgh' },
  { id: 11, cot: 19, name: 'Aryhh' },
  { id: 10, cot: 15, name: 'Yym' },
  { id: 7, cot: 15, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 3, cot: 15, name: 'Brt' },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const menu = [
    { id: 1, cot: 13, name: 'Art' },
    { id: 2, cot: 13, name: 'Aghgrt' },
    { id: 3, cot: 15, name: 'Brt' },
    { id: 4, cot: 13, name: 'dfr' },
    { id: 5, cot: 19, name: 'cft' },
    { id: 6, cot: 19, name: 'Atgh' },
    { id: 7, cot: 15, name: 'Art' },
    { id: 8, cot: 19, name: 'yrt' },
    { id: 9, cot: 13, name: 'Arr' },
    { id: 10, cot: 15, name: 'Yym' },
    { id: 11, cot: 19, name: 'Aryhh' },
    { id: 12, cot: 13, name: 'Arhjthj' },
];

menu.sort((prev, next) => prev.cot - next.cot);

console.log(menu);

[
  { id: 1, cot: 13, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 2, cot: 13, name: 'Aghgrt' },
  { id: 4, cot: 13, name: 'dfr' },
  { id: 9, cot: 13, name: 'Arr' },
  { id: 12, cot: 13, name: 'Arhjthj' },
  { id: 3, cot: 15, name: 'Brt' },
  { id: 7, cot: 15, name: 'Art' },
  { id: 10, cot: 15, name: 'Yym' },
  { id: 5, cot: 19, name: 'cft' },
  { id: 6, cot: 19, name: 'Atgh' },
  { id: 8, cot: 19, name: 'yrt' },
  { id: 11, cot: 19, name: 'Aryhh' }
]
```